# Java Build in Sublime 3

Tags: java, sublimetext3

I'm trying to set up a build so that I can compile and run Java in sublime 3. My build system isn't working.

```
"cmd": "java ${file_name} && java ${file_base_name}",
"file_regex": "^[ ]file \"(...?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath\\java.exe",
"selector": "source.java",
"shell":true
```

I have this build saved to my packages and it appears in the build menu, but when I try and run it, it says that there is no build working.

Comment: `javac` is the Java compiler...

Answer (score 3):

Please read the [build system documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html) for information on how to structure `.sublime-build` files. `"cmd"` and `"path"` are lists, not strings, so that's one reason you may be getting an error. Another reason, as I mentioned in the comments, is that you are trying to compile your `.java` file with `java` instead of `javac`. Finally, your `"path"` is incorrect — it should point to a list of directories, not files. This may work better for you:

```js
{
    "cmd": ["javac", "${file_name}", "&&", "java", "${file_base_name}"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]file \"(...?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "path": ["C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath"],
    "selector": "source.java",
    "shell": true
}
```

Comment: In my case the path is pointing to `C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_66\\bin\\`. But be aware that Sublime Text might not be a good option for running your Java code. The [forum of sublime text 3](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/using-sublime-text-3-as-a-java-ide/14156) provides an explanation for that.

Comment: @SoS I wholeheartedly agree that Sublime is not the best choice for a Java IDE, although the [`Javatar`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Javatar) plugin goes some way towards improving that. Especially for beginners, Eclipse or IntelliJ or Netbeans or whatever are much better choices, as they offer better code intelligence, inline documentation, import organization, and the ability to compile complex projects out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

**Try this. It worked for me on Mac.**

Step 1: Go to Sublime Text Preferences and click on Browse Packages.

Step 2: Create Java folder if there is no Java folder.

Step 3: Create JavaC.sublime-build and add following code and save it.

```
{
"shell_cmd": "javac \"$file_name\" && java \"$file_base_name\"",
"file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.java",

"variants":
[
    {
        "name": "Syntax Check",
        "shell_cmd": "javac \"$file_name\" && java \"$file_base_name\"",
    }
]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
{
    "file_regex": "(.+):(\\d+): error: ",
    "shell_cmd": "javac $file && java $file_base_name",
    "shell": true,
    "selector": "source.java",
}
```

its working on windows sublime text 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works on linux. Not sure about Windows.

```
{
    "cmd": ["javac '$realpath$file' && java $file_base_name && rm *.class"],
    "selector": "source.java",
    "shell": true,
    "variants": [

        {
            "name": "JavaDoc",
            "cmd": ["mkdir documentation && javadoc -d documentation *.java"]
        },

        {
            "name": "JAR",
            "cmd": ["javac '$realpath$file' && echo \"Main-Class: $file_base_name\" > Manifest.txt && jar cfm $file_base_name.jar Manifest.txt *.class && rm *.class && java -jar $file_base_name.jar"]
        },


    ]
}
```

This works for me on Linux and can be downloaded on Github at [Java.sublime-build](https://gist.github.com/tushortz/5fc717d4bddedf5b560b)

The interesting thing is that it also compile files to JAR. Remove classes  after compilation to make things neater and it also support generating JavaDocs.

The only limitation is that it cannot accept user input or arguments at compile time. You would have to do that manually in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

JavaC.sublime-build sample to set java classpath path when running java code.

```
{
  "shell_cmd": "javac -encoding utf-8 $file_name && java -cp .:/path/* $file_base_name && rm -rf $file_base_name.class",
  "file_regex": "^ *\\[javac\\] (.+):([0-9]+):() (.*)$",
  "selector": "source.java",
  "encoding": "utf-8"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Windows:

```
{
"cmd": ["java", "$file"]
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).