# Problem when compiling JavaFX with Sublime Text 3

Tags: javafx

I've recently started a project working with JavaFX and am using Sublime Text as IDE. 
When compiling with the built-in system in S.T I get errors while importing JavaFX packages.
Compiling and running in terminal works fine,

`javac --module-path %PATH_TO_FX% --add-modules javafx.controls GUIExample.java`

`java --module-path %PATH_TO_FX% --add-modules javafx.controls GUIExample`

I've been looking around and I can't manage to find out how to be able to build JavaFX in S.T.
Any help is very appreciated.
/Best Splinter

*(I am running: jdk-13.0.1, Windows 10)*

Comment: You obviously need to configure your _build system_. Maybe you can post what you have now. By the way, does this help: [Java Build in Sublime 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960540/java-build-in-sublime-3)

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the java build path for your sublime text editor.

1. Click on Preferences->Browse Packages
2. Navigate to Java Folder->JavaC.sublime-build
3. Modify the contents of this file as:

```
{
    "file_regex": "(.+):(\\d+): error: ",
    "shell_cmd": "javac $file && java $file_base_name",
    "shell": true,
    "selector": "source.java",
}
```

Also Sublim Text is a Text Editor and not an IDE. I will not recommend to use Sublime Text for Java Development. You can go for Eclipse or IntelliJ Idea as your Java IDE.